# Flavor 'nativescript-ui-listview' has unknown dimension 'nativescript-ui-listview'

Tags: nativescript

i have trouble using the nativecript-ui-listview plugin,it happens after the "tns run android" command

> Preparing project... Successfully prepared plugin
>   nativescript-theme-core for android. Successfully prepared plugin
>   nativescript-ui-listview for android. Successfully prepared plugin
>   tns-core-modules for android. Successfully prepared plugin
>   nativescript-ui-core for android. Successfully prepared plugin
>   tns-core-modules-widgets for android. Project successfully prepared
>   (Android) Building project... Gradle build...
>
> > IDLE Error: read ECONNRESET
> >         at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
> >         at TCP.onread (net.j<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [1s]
> >              + applying user-defined configuration from C:\Users\lenovo\appname\app
>
> \App_Resources\Androi d\app.gradle Configuration 'compile' in project
>   ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead. Configuration
>   'debugCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use
>   'debugImplementation'
>
> instead.
>            + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized
>            + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\lenovo\appname\node_modules\nativescript-
>
> ui-listvi ew\platforms\android\TNSListView-release.aar
>            + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\lenovo\appname\node_modules\nativescript-
>
> ui-core\p latforms\android\TNSCore-release.aar
>            + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\lenovo\appname\node_modules\tns-core-
>
> modules-widge ts\platforms\android\widgets-release.aar
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > Flavor 'nativescript-ui-listview' has unknown dimension 'nativescript-ui-listview'.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to
>
> get more l og output.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 16s

Answer (score 0):

Detail you have provided is not clear. Can you please clear you issue with more detail.
It seems that nativescript-ui-listview is not added properly.